# Is there something like ZenTest/Autotest for Java and JUnit

Tags: java, ruby, unit-testing, tdd, autotest

I've used ZenTest and autotest to work on Ruby projects before, and I used to using them for test-driven development a la [this configuration](http://blog.internautdesign.com/2006/11/12/autotest-growl-goodness). I have a project that I'm currently working on in Java, and I was wondering if there is something similar in the Java world to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Hier is the solution http://infinitest.github.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might I also suggest Infinitest, it is under active development and works with other languages besides Java. I believe it works fine with Scala, but I haven't had much luck using it with Groovy.

It is free for personal use and is being developed by Improving.

Comment: verified, 30 seconds later I had tests running automatically for a Spring app on STS

Answer (score 2):

I use junit max which is a eclipse plugin written by kent beck

Comment: Yes, JUnit max does exactly what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a lot of people use autotest like tools in java, there is one (although not so mature).

[A blog about it](http://nilanjan-braincasting.blogspot.com/2008/03/autotest-for-java.html).

[Autotest for java](http://code.google.com/p/autotest4j/).

Answer (score 0):

I used the tool and looks pretty cool for first release.. I would request him to come up with next version soon...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this a couple of weeks ago when I had to start doing some java. I couldn't find anything anywhere (being new to java) and I don't use eclipse so I hacked this together and will hopefully make it more useful in the future when I find some time:

http://github.com/feydr/crappe